# Some Windows 7 compatible utilities for console/command-line junkies?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit, console

As a command-line junkie, I routinely use quite a variety of tools from LIST to PC-Write 3.02 (used as a text editor with word-wrap, box-mode processing, and a few other tricks), QBASIC (nice for really quick one-off programs) etc.  While console utilities have some definite limitations, it can be nice to view a file and be returned to the command line when exiting the viewer (even if I've used other windows in the interim).  Since those things won't work in Windows 7 without an emulator, what would be my best approach?  Are there other utilities people would recommend that can run within a command-line window, or are there any emulators that can run within the command-line window that launched them (preferably wedged in as a replacement for the 'DOS no longer supported' message)?  What would people recommend?

Comment: They won't work in Windows 7 64-bit without an emulator, you mean.

Answer (score 5):

Along the same lines as GNUWin32, there's [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) - Linux apps for Windows (mostly command-line).

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `cmd.exe`, use [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx).

It is more powerful, more consistent and gives direct access to .NET, COM and WMI. Remoting included. Installed by default in Win7/2008R2 and available for supported earlier versions.

Best thing: replacing a text pipeline between commands with an object pipeline (no need to parse and re-parse numbers, dates, ... -- they keep their type).

Most applications (command line or window) will run from within PowerShell (as they would in `cmd.exe`).

Answer (score 3):

It's amazing that this question even need be asked in the 21st century.  Most of the stalwarts of the "power utilities" MS/PC/DR-DOS user have had Win32 equivalents and better since the 1990s.  In fact it's been so long that several *Windows* TUI tools have had time to themselves fall by the wayside.  Here's a small taste of what's still around now:

- Microsoft's own [Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx) comes in the box with Windows 7 Ultimate edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 and supports the [downloadable SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F).  (For Windows XP, one can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778) and install [Services for UNIX version 3.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb496506.aspx).)  This toolkit has a large number of command-line TUI tools, from `mv` and `du`, through the Korn and C shells, to `perl` and `awk`; and it comes in both x86-64 and IA64 flavours as well as x86-32.
- [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccledes.htm) has a built-in [LIST command](http://jpsoft.com./help/list.htm) amongst many others.
- Several TUI orthodox file managers, including [File Commander for Windows](http://silk.apana.org.au./fc.html) and [FAR](http://farmanager.com./), still exist.
- The [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb842062) contains several TUI tools for system tasks, such as `ListDLLs` and `LDMDump`.

The [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://microsoft.com./downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en), which contain *another* LIST program, are an example some of the Windows TUI tools that have since fallen by the wayside.  There's no equivalent for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

For a command-line junkie, [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) without a doubt. A lot of powerful GNU utilities ported to Windows in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

You might try installing andLinux: http://www.andlinux.org/ for access to many GNU and command line and linux tools.