# Unix command line utilities for Windows x64?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

There are many packages of [UNIX command line utilities for 32-bit Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/56224/where-can-i-find-windows-versions-of-commonly-used-unix-command-line-utilities). Now that the [mingw-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) Windows compiler is stable, I was expecting similar utilities to appear for 64-bit Windows (e.g. "GnuWin64"). However, I'm not finding them. Where are they?

Comment: What benefit do you believe they'll provide you?

Comment: For the most part, the 32-bit utilities work great. But I do work with multi-gigabyte files, for which there are limitations (e.g. [Value too large for defined data type](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type))

Comment: [for multi-gigabyte files] should you not work with better alternatives to emulation? Like, a dual-boot with Linux or a VM.

Comment: @nik, I use both Win/POSIX systems, but because I use *both* of these, I'd like to use a similar GNU toolset. For example, to compare `md5sum` checks of files on both systems.

Answer (score 8):

As I've mentioned on SuperUser [one](https://superuser.com/questions/251218) … [two](https://superuser.com/questions/251507) … [three](https://superuser.com/questions/255760) times:

The tools in the [SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F), which run in the [Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx) that comes right there in the box with Windows 7 Ultimate edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 (For Windows XP, one can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778) and install [Services for UNIX version 3.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb496506.aspx).), come in both AMD64 and IA64 flavours as well as x86-32.  This toolkit has a large number of command-line TUI tools, from `mv` and `du`, through the Korn and C shells, to `perl` and `awk`.  The programs run in Windows NT's native proper POSIX environment, rather than with emulator DLLs (such as `cygwin1.dll`) layering things over Win32 as other toolsets do.

Answer (score 7):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) started providing 64-bit versions a few month ago(July 2013)

Comment: On my Windows device, this folder contains exe and DLL dependencies: `C:\cygwin64\bin`

Answer (score 6):

SFUA utilities are not the same as the GNU ones.  They are largely incompatible, and only implement a very small subset of the Posix functions.

There are few utilities that would see any gain from Win64 memory addressing are the newer ones related to compression.  Most of those have Win64 builds available on their project site.  Simply use that version instead.

As for the libraries, if you are using them in a project, I recommend building the dll yourself if one is not available on other pages.  I recommend against updating the dll libraries that came with other projects.  There is a reason they shipped the version they did.  Simply get an updated version of the whole package if you need to address an issue in the dll.

Answer (score -2):

Found this link for ssed that works on 32- and 64-bit Windows

http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks these details should be edited into your answer.